# (spark jdbc) SQLRecoverableException: I/O Exception: Connection reset

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jdbc, oracle19c, emr-serverless

I have been working on a request that extracts data from an ORACLE 19c instance, and that is processed using aws emr-serveless using spark jdbc connections.

The big picture is that I can't connect to the database because of the error below:
19.15.0.0.1.jar, with Java 17, and I always get an error:

`java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset, Authentication lapse 0 ms.`

I've been stuck in it for almost 2 months, and unfortunately I'm not getting past this block. I have an application on emr serveless aws emr-6.13.0, ojdbc10-19.15.0.0.1.jar, with Java 17, and I always get an error.

Here are a few things I've already tested:

- older versions of emr serveless
- jdbc8, jdbc10, jdbc11, even compiled in specific versions for oracle 19c.
- I've used Java 8 and Java 17 as runtime
- Using pure python, I can connect to the database with Lambda and also as EC2 (I did the test to ensure that other aws services can connect using the necessary VPC).
- I have ensured that I have network connections, as I can ping, nslookup, and tellnet the destination.

After all, I don't know what to do about this mistake and I don't have any ideas that might be useful.

I'll also make my sparkSubmitParameters available, these are the settings I'm using at the moment.:

```
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djavax.net.debug=all 
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djavax.net.debug=all 
--conf spark.jars=s3://xxxxxxx/emr-serverless/ojdbc10-19.15.0.0.1.jar 
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom 
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom 
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dsecurerandom.source=file:/dev/./urandom 
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dsecurerandom.source=file:/dev/./urandom 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true  
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.shuffleTracking.enabled=true 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=1 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=30 
--conf spark.driver.cores=8 
--conf spark.executor.cores=8 
--conf spark.driver.memory=52g 
--conf spark.executor.memory=52g 
--conf spark.emr-serverless.driver.disk=200g 
--conf spark.emr-serverless.executor.disk=200g 
--conf spark.emr-serverless.driverEnv.JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-amazon-corretto.x86_64/ 
--conf spark.executorEnv.JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-amazon-corretto.x86_64/
```

Can anyone help me?
Any help is welcome.

Comment: Are you able to look at the Oracle logs and see if there's anything relevant? Given the "Connection reset" aspect of the error, it seems like an initial connection is being made?

Comment: I can request the log, what should I look at in this analysis?

Comment: Any information or errors around the time your job was trying to connect. I would run a job and then ask for logs between the start/end time of the job and look for any authentication errors.

Comment: I was able to get the log from a DBA team:
`VERSION INFORMATION:
 TNS for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
 Oracle Bequeath NT Protocol Adapter for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0
 TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0
  Version 19.17.0.0.0
  Time: 26-OCT-2023
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12535
    
TNS-12535: TNS:operation timed out
    ns secondary err code: 12606
    nt main err code: 0
    nt secondary err code: 0
    nt OS err code: 0
  Client address: (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=XX)(PORT=XX))`

Comment: That error message looks like a timeout error. :\ When you said you did tests with EC2, was it in the exact same VPC/subnet/security group that your EMR Serverless application is using? You can also try the reachability analyzer to verify connectivity: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/reachability/what-is-reachability-analyzer.html

Comment: So, yes, I made sure I was using the same VPC/Subnet/Security Group.